# Why does Boolean(Infinity) gives true?

Tags: javascript, nan, infinity

Can someone please explain Why does Boolean(Infinity) is true but Boolean(NaN) is false?

> Infinity || true

expression gives Infinity.
`

> NaN || true

` expression gives true.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2: `ToBoolean(Number): The result is false if the argument is +0, −0, or NaN; otherwise the result is true.`

Comment: Because `Infinity` is quite a substantially large number, while `NaN` even has "not" in the name...?

Comment: Please tell us what is the case that this matters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EMCAScript's [logical OR](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11) casts its arguments to booleans using [`ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which behaves as follows for numbers:

> The result is `false` if the argument is `+0`, `−0`, or `NaN`; otherwise the result is `true`.

Thus, `NaN` becomes `false`, and `Infinity` becomes `true`. We sometimes refer to values as "truthy" or "falsy" depending on whether `ToBoolean` coerces them to `true` or `false`.

If you look at the spec for logical OR, the operator returns either the *original* `lval` or `rval` (left/right value), not its coerced boolean value. This is why `(Infinity || true) == Infinity`: the value of `ToBoolean(lval)`  is `true`, so the expression returns the original `lval`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a combination of two things: How "truthiness" is tested, and the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html).

1. **Truthiness**: When using boolean logic in JavaScript, the arguments are converted to booleans. How this happens is covered in the spec, [Section 9.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2), which says amongst other things that when converting a value to a boolean from a number:

   > The result is `false` if the argument is `+0`, `−0`, or `NaN`; otherwise the result is `true`.
2. **Curiously-powerful `||` operator**: JavaScript's `||` operator does not evalute to `true` or `false`. It evaluates to its left-hand argument if that argument is "truthy," or its right-hand argument otherwise. So `1 || 0` is `1`, not `true`; and `false || 0` is `0` (even though `0` is falsey). So for the same reason, `Infinity || true` is `Infinity`, not `true`.

   This feature of `||` is *incredibly* powerful. You can do things like this, for instance:

   ```
   someElement.innerHTML = name || "(name missing)";
   ```

   ...and if `name` is **not** `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `false`, or `NaN`, `innerHTML` gets set to `name`; if it *is* one of those values, it gets set to `"(name missing")`.

   Similarly, you can have default objects:

   ```
   var obj = someOptionalObject || {};
   ```

   The uses are many and varied. You do have to be careful, though, that you don't unintentionally weed out *valid* `falsey` values like `0` when you're defaulting things in this way. :-)

   A chain of `||` operators strung together (`a || b || c`) returns the first truthy argument in the chain, or the last argument if none of them are truthy.

   The `&&` operator does something quite similar: It returns its first argument if that argument is *falsey*, or its right argument otherwise. So `0 && 1` is `0`, not `false`. `2 && 1` is `1`, because `2` is not falsey. And chains of them return the first falsey arg, or the last arg, which is handy when you need to get a property from a nested object:

   ```
   var prop = obj && obj.subobj && obj.subobj.property || defaultValue;
   ```

   ...returns `obj` if it's falsey, or `obj.subobj` if it's falsey, or `obj.subobj.property` if neither of the first two is falsey. Then the result of that `|| defaultValue` gives you either the property, or the default.

Comment: May be worth noting that `&&` behaves almost the same way  (return the value of the element that short-circuits the boolean expression) `NaN && true` would return `NaN`. `||` can be used for defaulting and `&&` can be used for null checking. `if (a && a.b && a.b.c)`

Answer (score 0):

It is because **NaN stands for "not a number"**, practically speaking it has no value. In certain languages (like Java, AS3) this is the default value of an uninitialized floating point variable. However Infinity (no matter positive/negative) is a valid representation of an unreachable value.

When you convert their numeric value to boolean, it has come into effect.